# Azure Alert based on reading Odata

Tags: azure, api, odata, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

I have an application installed on a VM that publishes a page via OData.
I need to be able to trigger a high urgency alert based on one specific value published by the page.
I am little aware of Application Insights to monitor applications in Azure. But I am not sure if there is a way to read the data from the API and trigger an alert.
What options do I have to accomplish this in Azure?

Answer (score 1):

Pls allow me to share my idea here.

[creating app insights alert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-log#create-a-log-alert-rule-with-the-azure-portal)

[enable app insights for azure vm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-vm-vmss-apps)

First, adding app insights to your application can made AI to capture your requests, dependencies, logs and some other messages, including calling API.

In my thoughts, I can log the response message of the API and set alert for some specific keywords. I created an azure function, and it will call MS graph API when triggered, and log the response. This function has integrated AI, so I created an alert by kql:

```
 traces
| where timestamp > ago(30m) and message contains "xxx"
```

and set alert rule based on number of results greater than 0. When the alert was triggered, it will send email to my mailbox to mention me.

This means any time my API returned the response contains specific words, I will receive an email about it.

[image]